# Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar shows white actionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I can't seem to fix it.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    ...
```

And I have imported actionBarSherlock and implemented it seemingly correct. 
The Theme.Sherlock and Theme.Sherlock.Light works perfectly.

Comment: Show us your whole manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

which i used in another app to remove the blue divider. However in this design, it just removed the whole background.

Now the design works as it's suppose to, but I'm stuck with some sort of horizontal divider between the actionbar and the content.